# stringify detached entity in breeze

Tags: json, breeze, stringify

Is there a way to stringify detached entity in breeze?

It is possible to do via

```
creating appropriate manager
...
manager.addEntity(myEntity);
var str = manager.exportEntities(myEntity);
```

I just search the simplest way to do it without using managers.
something like JSON.stringify(myEntity)... but it returns an error.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that entities have relationships with other entities, and the resulting graph can be recursive and is also often very large so you will need some method of serializing a possibly recursive entity graph. This is what is done inside of the *exportEntities* call.

If what you need is just the data properties of an entity then the code can be much simpler. Simply copy all of the *data properties* of an entity ( list of data properties is available from the entityType) into an empty javascript object and then stringify this copy. Of course this will not give you *entityState* information or *originalValues* for the entity, but I can't tell if you need these.